# How do I give pages a special url to open externally

Tags: php

I'm creating a website where there are topics, which you can view using session variables if you click on an item in a list (topics page). I however, want to have it so that you can use a url like: 'www.forum.nl/topicname'. I have seen it everywhere, but I don't know how to use it and how it is called.

edit: Ok now how I did what I did: I know I am not supposed to do this, but I have no clue how .htacces works. I thought I used session variables used window.location because I didn't know the other way.

`onclick='window.location = url; window.name='".$result[$1][\'name\']` to go to a new page and have the name of the topic in window.name

Then for a test i did `alert(window.name);`

but this doesn't have to do with what I want. I want to know how I can make it so that www.domain.nl/topic1 goes to topic 1, and www.domain.nl/topic2 goes to topic 2.

Comment: see [.htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/.htaccess/info)

Comment: what do you mean `session variables`? Please provide some sample code of what you have

Comment: I think you mean query parameters instead of session variables.

Comment: added, but that doesn't have to do with what I need

Comment: Yes, but that's what I don't know how to do Philip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways of doing this, all varying in difficulty. By far the easiest way is by using simple query parameters ([$_GET](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)):

First, make a new page in your docroot: `viewTopic.php`

```
/* file viewTopic.php */

if( isset($_GET['topicName']) ){
    /* test */
    echo 'topicName selected is '.htmlspecialchars($_GET['topicName']);
}else{
    echo 'topicName is not set!';
}
```

Now, a simple test: visit `http://localhost/viewTopic.php?topicName=hello+world`

Next, an example of a topic item (on `topics.php` page for instance):

```
/* file topics.php */

<ul>
    <li><a href="http://localhost/viewTopic.php?topicName=hello+world">Hello World</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://localhost/viewTopic.php?topicName=topicNum2">Foo</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://localhost/viewTopic.php?topicName=barTopic">Bar</a></li>
</ul>
```

More advanced methods include [url rewriting](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/introduction-to-url-rewriting/) and a [routing system](https://medium.com/the-andela-way/how-to-build-a-basic-server-side-routing-system-in-php-e52e613cf241), which will take some reading to understand.